# sending data from model to controller in codeigniter 1.7.2

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I am receiving `$fb_data[uid]` i.e Facebook UID from my model and I want to put this variable's value into my controller where the signup process is taking place
 passing fields in controller like this:

```
$sql_data = array('student_fname' => $student_fname, 'student_sname' => $student_sname, 'student_org' => $student_org, 'student_title' => $student_title, 'student_uid' => ?
```

I am confused how to insert the Facebook UID value here at my controller..

Comment: Can you please post some code? I'm a little bit confused why you're confused. Does `$fb_data['uid']` exist in the model method?

Comment: yes it exists in my model.... after user sign in through facebook to my website.

Comment: Ok, then you need the model method to return the Facebook UID (and some other data if needed), then in the controller it should be trivial to access the Facebook UID. I'm guessing the method you have in the model doesn't return anything (Or at least anything but the UID from Facebook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a function in your model which returns your `$fb_data`. In the controller you have (if not already done) to load the model

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```

Then you can access your model function from the controller by calling

```
$this->model_name->function_name();
```

The section 'loading a model' in the [CI documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html) explains it again.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

First create one method in controller :

Ex : In controller

```
function fbcontent() {
$this->load->model('your model name');
$content = $this->model_name->fbaction();
}
```

and In model

```
function fbaction(){
$sql_data = array('student_fname' => $student_fname, 'student_sname' => $student_sname, 'student_org' => $student_org, 'student_title' => $student_title, 'student_uid' => ?
return $sql_data;
}
```

Comment: here is my model   function set_session_data(){   
                 //set session variable return true if set else false
  try {   
   $user=$this->get_user();
   $fqlResult   =   $this->facebook->api('/'.$user);
   //print_r($fqlResult);
   $fb_data = array(
       'uid' => $fqlResult['id'],
       'full_name' => $fqlResult['name'],
       'email' =>$fqlResult['email'],
       'is_logged_in' =>'1'
       );  
   //session create   
   $this->session->set_userdata($fb_data);         i am getting facebook uid as "$fb_data[uid]"       now how to insert that value along with others in controller

Comment: it worked after loading model into controller and then calling function  which was returning data in model by returning $fb_data in model... thanks guys i appreciate your help.